# Create database and collection using mongo.exe

Tags: mongodb

What is the syntax for creating a database and collection using mongo.exe and an inine command string?
I have tried (server and password masked):

mongo.exe MY_SERVER/admin -u MongoDBA -p MY_PASS --eval "use mytest;db.createCollection('mytemptestCollection')"

This gives Syntax error "Missing ; before statement".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, leaving the answer here in case anyone can make use of it:

```
mongo.exe MY_SERVER:27017/admin -u MongoDBA -p MY_PASSWORD --eval "db=db.getSiblingDB('mytest');db.createCollection('myTestCollection')"
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB use DATABASE_NAME is used to create database. The command will create a new database if it doesn't exist, otherwise it will return the existing database.

MongoDB db.createCollection(name, options) is used to create collection.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_create_database.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_create_collection.htm

Comment: Thank's but the use helper is not a usable command in this context. That was my problem.